# How do I get animated swipe background effect in Listview, similar to swipe to call feature in android enabled phone

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, side-effects

I have an app developed using jquery mobile and build using phonegap. I wanted to achieve the similar effect as that of "swipe to call" feature in android enabled phones in my listview.

[image]

Not sure how to go forward. checked some other posts but those where examples related to core android development environment.

When I swipe from right to left I get this message, but not sure how to get the background effect.

```
$(document).on('swipeleft', '.forSwipe', function(e){
    alert("right to left");
});
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anyone please help me out with the above query... I am struggling with this for past few days now.

Comment: did anyone manage to get something on this???